# Which to use mod_perl vs mod_fcgi vs mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: perl, cgi

In our web application we show job current status using a grid, the user can select multiple records and click on the action to change the state of jobs. On action click, we send the action to vanilla CGI for each job selected which spawn Perl script to change state. We do this because each job can be run as a different user the person taking action should have sudo privileges to take action.

We are planning to improve performance by sending all selected jobs details and spawning process to take action on jobs. While exploring more for CGI I came across CGI, mod_perl, mod_fcgi, proxy_fcgi on Apache side and Starman, dancer, catalyst, and plack on Perl side. Now, I'm more confused which one to use.

Comment: We cannot really tell you what to use. If you want persistent processes, any PSGI/Plack solution will work. It doesn't sound like a web framework would help you, so no Dancer, Catalyst or Mojolicious. You can easily write vanilla PSGI. But you can also use Dancer and not use template. Anyway you will have to rework quote a bit because it sounds like your scripts are all one off things that will not just support persistence without changes. Look at the deployment guide for Plack to see how to get it running in prod, with or without Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Your post refers to a mix of technologies that serve a variety of purposes.

It sounds like you have a straight CGI Perl script, and you want to improve its performance.

Academic conversations aside, I would suggest you focus on mod_fcgi.